# Put your app on your Twitter profile

Tags: twitter

I wanted to know if there's a way to make my app downloadable from my Twitter profile. Here are some examples
[image: two][image: one]

How would I do this? Are there certain parameters I need to meet with Twitter?

Answer (score 0):

Every Twitter user can add a link to the profile.  The link needs to be `http://` or `https://` those are the only restrictions.

To add this in your browser, visit your Twitter page when logged in and click the "edit profile" button.

To add this via the API, use [`account/update_profile`](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/account/update_profile) and add a `url` parameter.